# Opensuse kernel panic

Tags: opensuse, kernel-panic

The latest kernel update of opensuse leap is suffering from kernel panic. I am unable to run large programs like android studio. The pc freezes and caps Lock blinks. It happens also when laptop lid is closed. So how can I degrade the the Kernel to the stock one.

Answer (score 1):

simply `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (if they are using grub )
choose as the default kernel option the running kernel,
if there is you also have to map the associated `initrd` to the kernel that you have chosen
[image]

to view the current kernel version `uname -a` to see what other kernels are installed `ls /boot/`

Comment: Ok But after the two updates the old kernel option in grub  has been gone. So Now I need to download the old one but how

Comment: I'm afraid I did not understand , he fits into the grub vesione working kernel

Comment: The grub has two options. Normal boot and Advanced boot

Comment: in fact , in grub.cfg you can safely change the kernel parameter to normal boot

Comment: so do I need  to set the old kernal version in grub

Comment: The problem is that the Kernel that works fine  is completely removed during the System update.

Comment: in repositories is the old kernel ? or try to find the rpm